# Looking for a 1980s American zombie movie where the people in a hospital turn into a mannequin-like zombies without being bitten

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

They don't run, they just walk slowly. 
There is one scene where a few soldiers were trapped inside a glass walled room.
Also, there is this zombie in a red shirt who stares at the female soldier inside the glass walled room.

Comment: Reminds me of one of the _Living Dead_ films, possibly _[Return of the Living Dead 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_of_the_Living_Dead_3)_. It featured Trioxin, a gas that could zombify people without getting bitten.

Comment: I've seen Return of the Living Dead movies and sadly im looking for a different zombie movie. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Reminds me of [George Romero's _Day of the Dead_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088993/). Soldiers, zombie with a red shirt.